# How many spells does a 9th-level Sorcerer know?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, character-creation, sorcerer

I only just made my character, a Sorcerer, and I need to prepare my spells for the next DnD session. I'm joining mid-campaign, so my starting level is 9. I need to know how many spells I can have... I'm not asking how many spell uses I have, but rather how many unique spells I can learn, such as *fireball*, *pyrotechnics* or *fly*.

Comment: Your question could be seen as unclear as with items you can have way more spells known

Answer (score 4):

Spells for the sorcerer are laid out in the [sorcerer class definition](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/sorcerer#TOC-Spells).  I think the confusion may come from the two types of level involved: you have sorcerer levels, but spells have levels as well.  Just because you're a level 9 sorcerer does not mean you have level 9 spells available.  In general, your level will be much higher than the levels of the spells you have access to.

A 9th-level sorcerer has 8 0th-level spells, 5 first-level spells, 4 second-level spells, 3 third-level spells, and 2 fourth-level spells.  You will also have 4 additional spells from your [bloodline](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/sorcerer#TOC-Bloodline).  You don't get to choose these spells; they depend on your bloodline.  Assuming you have the [elemental bloodline](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/sorcerer/bloodlines/bloodlines-from-paizo/elemental-bloodline), your bonus spells would be burning hands, scorching ray, protection from energy, and elemental body I.